# Rails Cancancan Ajax custom action not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, cancancan

I have a Rails App to which I added Devise and Cancancan to authentication and authorization.
Before that, the actio worked correctly, now in the console browser I see a redirect to the home.

I call the action submitting the form in javascript

```
$("input[name='period']").click(function(){
if ($(this).val() == '1' || $(this).val() == '2' || $(this).val() == '3') {
  $('#form_search_dates').hide();
  var elem = $('#my-form')[0];
  $(elem).submit();
} 
else {
  $('#form_search_dates').show();
}
});
```

This is my controller action

```
class ShoppingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def search
    @shoppings = nil
    logger.debug "Dentro Search"
    @period = params[:period]
    if @period.present?
      logger.debug "Period: #{@period}"
      if @period == '1'
        logger.debug "Tutte"
        @shoppings = Shopping.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(date_shopping: :asc)
      elsif @period == '2'
        logger.debug "Ultimi 7 giorni"
        @date_end = Date.today
        @date_start = @date_end - 7
        @shoppings = Shopping.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:date_shopping => @date_start..@date_end).order(date_shopping: :asc)
      elsif @period == '3'
        logger.debug "Ultimi 30 giorni"
        @date_end = Date.today
        @date_start = @date_end - 30
        @shoppings = Shopping.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:date_shopping => @date_start..@date_end).order(date_shopping: :asc)
        end
      else
        logger.debug "No parametri"
        @shoppings = Shopping.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(date_shopping: :asc)
      end
   @result_total_price = @shoppings.sum(:total_price)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end
 end
```

And this is my ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
  can :create, Shopping
  can :read, Shopping, user_id: user.id
  can :update, Shopping, user_id: user.id
  can :destroy, Shopping, user_id: user.id
```

When I call the action clicking on radiobuttons, It does a redirect to the root url, and in console I see this

```
Started POST "/shoppings/search" for ::1 at 2023-12-19 12:18:00 +0100
Processing by ShoppingsController#search as JS
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "period"=>"2"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 2903)
```

I don't see the logs in the console, like it seems that it doesn't even start to execute the controller action, What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: `var elem = $('#my-form')[0];` needs to be `var elem = $('#my-form');`

Comment: Also, check the browser developer console for errors. If any then try to resolve them. You can share them here as well. It would be very useful if you could share the rendered form HTML of your browser.

Comment: I think you need to add the search action to the `ability.rb` file, just like `:create`, `:read'`etc

Answer (score 0):

this is the rendered HTML form

```
<form id="my-form" data-turbolinks="false" action="/shoppings/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="b4W-ish4XpxX_b6BSpIzeQ_sRLurmXmfFAJISUwuasOMZLK7ATRNMKmU4H4smqg-1WAnfdvZr4JJc2EyI8uFaw" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="period" id="period_1"> 
        <label class="label_index" for="period">Tutte</label>

        <input type="radio" value="2" name="period" id="period_2"> 
        <label class="label_index" for="period">Ultimi 7 giorni</label>

        <input type="radio" value="3" name="period" id="period_3"> 
        <label class="label_index" for="period">Ultimi 30 giorni</label>

        <input type="radio" value="4" name="period" id="period_4"> 
        <label class="label_index" for="period">Cerca per date</label>
    </div>
 </form>
```

In console I have the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "Turbolinks"... is not valid JSON

In Network tab in browser the answer is
`Turbolinks.clearCache() Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/", {"action":"replace"})`
It does not render the search.js.erb file in the Views folder